# what should i do if a sniper bot blocked me?

Tags: uniswap

Last week I have bought a token. after some transactions on it I couldn't buy or sell it anymore and even cant transfer that token to another wallet. I searched and somebody told me that a sniper bot in that tokens smart contract blocked me. now I don't know what should I do...
I appreciate any information that could help me

Comment: You probably bought a scam token. We cant help you if you dont post the token contract address and your personal address.

Comment: anyone else can buy it. i can buy it with another wallet too. Its address:0x55f96c7005d7c684a65ee653b07b5fe1507c56ab
Bsc bep20 .

Comment: What's the error that you get on failed transfer transactions? What is the revert reason on bscscan?